# Using binary in MySQL and PHP for flags

Tags: php, mysql, binary, bitwise-operators

Let's say I have the following flags that can be attached to a customer:

```
1 Hot
2 Urgent
4 Sensitive
8 Confidential
```

In my table I would store an active customer as an int of 6.

I figured doing things this way would save me a reference table and make querys faster.

How do I get PHP to interpret a 6 and for example light up a customer and active icon?

Comment: Someone can really be active *without* being a customer?  A prospect can be cancelled?  A prospect can be a customer?  I think you need to think harder about the flags and the states they represent.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Those are just quick examples. I have renamed them for you. Non are exclusive now but I get what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operators will do the trick:

```
$flag = 6; // value from the database
$customer = 2; // constant value
$active = 4; // constant value

if ($flag & $customer)
{
    print 'I am a customer.';
}

if($flag & $active)
{
    print 'I am active.';
}
```

I agree with @GordonLinoff though. Really consider if this is what you want because it's not easy to change later, and it could allow unexpected scenarios.

Comment: so problems arise when one can not be without another?

Comment: @imperium2335 yes, that's one example. Also consider the possibility that one classification is removed; or, a new one is added and should be a default all existing records. Also, in you original example, do prospects and customers really differ by only a flag? It's unlikely that your tables are normalized in that case. I'm not saying don't ever use bitwise flags, but just think carefully about whether it's appropriate.

Comment: No, that was a poor example, realistically there is a column for state, being prospect or customer. Those definitions are stored in a separate table.